# Can we say that this loop is not homologous to zero?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, surfaces, curves

Let $(S,g)$ be a closed and orientable Riemannian surface and let $\gamma : \mathbb{S}^1 \to S$ be a closed smooth curve. Suppose that there exists a (nonzero) closed differential $1$-form $\omega$ on $S$ such that $$\int_\gamma \omega \neq 0.$$

Can we conclude that the class of $\gamma$ in $H_1(S;\mathbb{Z})$ is nonzero?

If this is not the case, is there a criterion for "testing" the curve against cohomology classes to decide if it is homologous to zero?

Comment: Yes, this is basically the duality between homology and cohomology.

Comment: @AnginaSeng even when the homology is taken with integer coefficients and cohomology with real coefficients?

Comment: I think we can deduce that the homology class represented by $\gamma$ in $H_1 (S; \mathbb R)$, $[\gamma]_{\mathbb R}$ has to be nonzero. There is also natural map $\phi :H_1(S; \mathbb Z) \rightarrow H_1(S; \mathbb R)$ induced by $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb R$ so that $\phi ([ \gamma]_{\mathbb Z}) = [\gamma ]_{\mathbb R}$. Then $[ \gamma]_{\mathbb Z}$ can't be zero since its image under a homomorphism is nonzero.